# JPA/Hibernate - delete child removes parent (from same table)

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, many-to-one, hibernate-onetomany

I have a class Comment (see below) with some Comment objects belonging to a parent Comment.
So far, when I delete a parent Comment, the childs are also deleted (as expected), BUT the problem comes when a child is deleted because the parent is also removed.
I guess the problem comes from the JPA configuration used in the class.
Any ideas how to delete the childs without affecting the parent row?

```
 public class Comment {
   @Column  
   private String text;             

   @ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
   private Comment parent;

   @OneToMany(cascade={CascadeType.ALL}, mappedBy="parent")
   private Set<Comment> childs = new HashSet<Comment>();
}
```

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `cascade={CascadeType.ALL}` from mapping of `parent`:

```java
public class Comment {
   @Column  
   private String text;             

   @ManyToOne
   private Comment parent;

   @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="parent") // or orphanRemoval=true
   private Set<Comment> childs = new HashSet<Comment>();
}
```